# Respect the lowercase and uppercase letters when getting a mysql data

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to know how can i respect lowercase/uppercase letters when getting an information from a mysql server(phpmyadmin exactly), here is the working code, i made a register/login script and i would like to add it.

```
def checkLogin():
    global windowOpened
    
    getmail = emailEntry.get()
    getpass = passwordEntry.get()
    
    sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = %s AND password = %s"
    
    mycursor.execute(sql, [(getmail), (getpass)])
    results = mycursor.fetchall()
    
    if results:
        for i in results:
            logWindow.destroy()
            messagebox.showinfo("Succes", "Logged in succesfully!")
            windowOpened = 0
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Email or password are incorrect.")
```

if i enter the password full uppercase, it is still correct, even if the password is full lowercase.

Comment: `getpass` is really a string so you can manipulate in the way you like

Comment: Please repost your code with proper formatting. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You shouldn't store passwords in plaintext in the first place, you should be hashing it.

Comment: Would you show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` please?

Comment: Use [`hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#key-derivation) to hash your passwords.

Comment: there's no worrying about the password brothers, its not even an official app, i made it in 1 hour lol

Answer (score 1):

You should use `BINARY` to make your query case-sensitive:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = BINARY %s AND password = BINARY %s
```

Comment: thank you, appreciate the fast reply.